# How well-known is the Court?

Tags: gunnerkrigg-court

Gunnerkrigg Court itself seems to be quite large (at least the size of a small city), with train connections to other parts of the country. It also seems to be in Britain, which is relatively small.

How many people are aware of it? Is it totally hidden from view? Very obscure? Well-known but considered to be just a boarding school? Widely known as a magical research institute?

Comment: I always assumed it was in some non-specified part of an alternate universe. The adjoining forest also seems to be quite large, larger than any normal forest in Britain.

Comment: As to your question, I seem to remember from the first few chapters that it was known as a boarding school, but that it was much larger than people expected, and that nobody really knew who built most of it and why.

Comment: It grew from the seed Bismuth

Comment: AFAIK it's as secret as a city could be ;) Some people heard about school, some may know there's a city, but G.C. is very cagey about details.